# pip keep collecting many Tensorflow versions when installing alibi==0.5.5

Tags: python, installation, dependencies

I'm using a python project and installing its dependencies. The following are all the packages I need to install.

```
torch==1.3.0
numpy==1.15.0
pandas==0.25.2
scikit-learn==0.23.1
pyod==0.8.2
tqdm==4.48.2
prettytable==0.7.2
shap==0.36.0
lime==0.2.0.1
alibi==0.5.5
```

I put them in a `requirements.txt` file. Then I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

The problem happens that, I can install everything successfully before the last one, `alibi==0.5.5`. When installing it, it seems require a tensorflow >= 2.0. That's okay. But when the installation starts, it keeps collecting all tensorflow versions >= 2.0, as is shown in the figure. Why does this happen? How can I deal with it?

Thank you all for helping me!!!

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. System info?

Comment: @Seth Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux

Comment: @pfc I'm also facing the same issue with version 0.6.0, have you found any solutions? My python version is 3.8.